Vanishing (infinite) tensor products
Since the advent of free probabilities and QFT, infinite tensor products of $R$-associative algebras with units has become more familiar to the working mathematician.
Starting from the (permuting) tensor product of two $R$-associative algebras with units ($R$-AAU), one can define the infinite tensor product
$\otimes_{I\in I}\,E_i$ as the solution of the following universal problem (no need to suppose the algebras themselves to be commutative as it is not required here the object to be a categorical coproduct). The solution comes as a family
$(\otimes_{I\in I}\,E_i, j_i)$ with
$j_i:E_i\to \otimes_{I\in I}\,E_i$ to be morphims of $R$-AAU.
It is formalised as follows.
Let $(E_i,e_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family (finite or infinite) of $R$-AAU and, for each $i\in I$, let be given $\varphi_i:\ E_i\to\ \mathcal{A}$ be a (unital) morphism of $R$-AAU ($\mathcal{A}$ being a fixed $R$-AAU) with commuting images i.e. such that, for all $i,j\in I$ with $i\not= j$, one has
$$
\varphi_i(x)\varphi_j(y)=\varphi_j(y)\varphi_i(x)
$$
then. there is a unique (unital) morphim
$\Phi:\otimes_{I\in I}\,E_i\to\ \mathcal{A}$ such that, for all $i\in I$, $\Phi\circ j_i=\varphi_i$ (see e.g. Bourbaki, Algebra, §  4.5 Prop. 8).
On the one hand, we know that, if all $E_i$ are augmented algebras, all the $j_i$'s are injective, on the other hand it is known that tensor products can vanish (even if $|I|=2$ and  $R.e_i$ is direct summand in all $E_i$, think of $\mathbb{Z}/2.\mathbb{Z}[X]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/3.\mathbb{Z}[X]\simeq \{0\}$).   So, below is my question
Question: Are there known necessary and sufficient conditions such that the $j_i$ be all injective ?

A left $R$-module $A$ is flat if $- \otimes_R A$ preserves monos, and similarly we can say an $R$-bimodule is flat if tensoring on the right and left preserves monos. So if the ring maps $R \to E_i$ are all injective and all the $E_i$ are flat as $R$-bimodules, this would seem to do the trick (prove first for finitely many tensor factors, then take the filtered colimit or directed union to extend to infinitely many tensor factors).

@ToddTrimble Todd Ah I see. My case is softer ($R$ is commutative, so all algebras here are $R$-bimodules), but your condition seems weaker than the sufficient condition I gave (augmented algebras) and therefore the result would be stronger. Thanks, I will explore that. How about a necessary and sufficient condition ? (+1)
